# Slimbox - hover not working, close button not produced

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, hover, slimbox

I have some small issues with the Slimbox 2 plugin (http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) for WordPress.

You can see that the left and right links are produced inside the live edtiro, however the hover is not working so they never show up.

The close button code is not produced at all.

I have tried to force the left and right graphics on the non hover, and added the close code in the appropriate place in a live editor:

```
#lbPrevLink {background:transparent url(../images/prev.gif) no-repeat 0 15%;}
#lbNextLink {background:transparent url(../images/next.gif) no-repeat 0 15%;}

<a id="lbCloseLink" href="#"></a>
```

Just to make sure the CSS was correct and it was not an issue with the images or something. All show up, so I had a look in the jQuery code, which I am not very familiar with but from what I can see it should produce the close button code at least, I was thinking the hover might be an issue with something being in front of it, however have not been able to confirm or fix that.

So now I am thinking there is some type of conflict going on, but usually errors in the console clears that up for me with jQuery related issues.

This is the site in question (just click on one of the images): http://www.thekula.com/collection/

Would appreciate some feedback/help or any guidance on how to move further with this particular issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, if anyone else comes with this problem go here and theres a fix for slimbox2.js https://code.google.com/p/slimbox/issues/detail?id=36

Basically happens because of an old jQuery version included with Slimbox which needs 1.9 or higher I believe.

The Issue:

When I activate slimbox, I expect the window to be darkened with a normally lighted picture showing next and prev tabs and a close button at the bottom.  Instead I see the picture and window darkened, no navigation or close links.  Clicking anywhere on the window removes the picture and lightens the window.

Fix:

Update jQuery or download the new slimbox2.js in the link provided.